# Creating start menu shortcuts, result is error LGHT0094

Tags: wix, windows-installer, startmenu

When adding start menu shortcuts light.exe will produce the LGHT0094 error:

```
            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Menu">
            <Directory Id="DirManufacturer" Name="Manufacturer">
                <Component Id="MenuManufacturer" Guid="" KeyPath="yes">
                    <CreateFolder Directory="Manufacturer">
                    </CreateFolder>
                </Component>
                <Directory Id="DirProduct" Name="Product">
                    <Component Id="MenuProduct" Guid="" KeyPath="yes">
                        <CreateFolder Directory="Product">
                        </CreateFolder>
                        <Shortcut Id="SHC_Program1" Name="Program 1" Target="[ApplicationRootDirectory]Program1.exe" />
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
```

What is wrong in my XML?

Could somebody tell me how to create subsequent menu items in the start menu?

- Start Menu

  - Manufacturer (this and all subsequent items have to be created by the Installer)

    - Product

      - Program 1
      - Program 2
        etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article [How To: Create a Shortcut on the Start Menu](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/create_start_menu_shortcut.htm) of WiX manual has exhaustive explanation of how to create this kind of shortcut.